# Difficulty in computing the full conditional for a Probit model (Hoff 6.3)

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayesian

In a course of Bayesian statistics, I have been given an excercise from Hoff, about the computations of some full conditional for the Probit model.
I have not great confidence with conditional probability computation.
So I would like to ask if the following resoning is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Consider the following Probit model:
$$Z_i=\beta x_i+\epsilon_i\qquad\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\sim_{iid}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$Y_i=\mathbb{1}_{(c,+\infty)}(Z_i)$$
where:

1. $\beta$,$c$ unknown parameters, for which we assume priors $\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_\beta^2)$, $c\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_c^2)$
2. the covariates $x_i$ are known and hence tretated as constants

We have to derive $p(\beta\mid z_{1:n}, y_{1:n}, c)$.

Clearly, $c$ and $y_{1:n}$ bring no information on $\beta$. Then:

$$p(\beta\mid z_{1:n},y_{1:n}, c)=p(\beta\mid z_{1:n})\propto p(z_{1:n}\mid\beta)p(\beta)$$
$$\propto\mathtt{exp}(-\frac{1}{2}\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(z_i-\beta x_i)^2+(\beta/\sigma_\beta)^2\})
                \propto \mathtt{exp}[-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\beta-\tilde{\mu}_\beta}{\tilde{\sigma}_\beta})^2]$$

where:
$$\tilde{\sigma}_\beta^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+\frac{1}{\sigma^2_\beta}\right)^{-1}\qquad\tilde{\mu}_\beta=\tilde{\sigma}_\beta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iz_i\right)$$
Hence, we conclude $p(\beta\mid z_{1:n}, y_{1:n}, c)\sim\mathcal{N}(\tilde{\mu}_\beta,\tilde{\sigma}_\beta)$

- **Question 1** Is this computation correct?

We have to derive $p(c\mid z_{1:n}, y_{1:n}, \beta)$
Clearly, $\beta$ brings no information on $c$.
Moreover, observe that $p(c\mid z_{1:n})=p(c)$, since $z_{1:n}$ alone brings no information on $c$.
Then:
$$ p(c\mid\beta,z_{1:n},y_{1:n})=p(c\mid z_{1:n},y_{1:n})\propto p(y_{1:n}\mid c,z_{1:n})p(c\mid z_{1:n})=p(y_{1:n}\mid c,z_{1:n})p(c)$$

Now, observe that $y_i\mid c,z_i$ is not random any more. In particular it is one if $z_i>c$ and it is $0$ if $z_i\leq c$. Then we may write, observing that $z_{-i}$ brings no information about $y_i$:
$$p(y_i\mid c,z_{1:n})=p(y_i\mid  c,z_i)=\mathbb{1}_{(z_i>c)}^{y_i}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i\leq c)}^{1-y_i}$$
Then:
$$p(y_{1:n}\mid c,z_{1:n})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i>c)}^{y_i}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i\leq c)}^{1-y_i}$$
And in turn:
$$p(c\mid\beta,z_{1:n},y_{1:n})\propto\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i>c)}^{y_i}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i\leq c)}^{1-y_i}\right)\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_c^2)$$

- **Question 2**According to a given hint,parenthesis should reduce to the charachterstic function of an interval, so that we have a truncated gaussian. But I cannot see how it can. can someone help?

We have to derive $p(z_i\mid z_{-i}, y_{1:n}, \beta, c)$. Clearly, $z_{-i}$ brings no information on $z_{-i}$, similarly for $y_{-i}$.
$$p(z_i\mid y_{i},\beta,c)\propto p(y_i\mid z_{i},\beta,c)p(c)
                    \propto p(y_i\mid z_{i},c)p(c)
                    \propto \mathbb{1}_{(z_i>c)}^{y_i}\mathbb{1}_{(z_i\leq c)}^{1-y_i}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_c^2)$$

- **Question 3** Is this computation correct?